# understand the combination of elements with replacement and order doesn't matter

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I am reading [Statistical Inference](https://mybiostats.files.wordpress.com/2015/03/casella-berger.pdf). Example 1.2.20 says the total number of unordered combinations of $\{2,4,9,12\}$, with replacement, is $\binom{4+4-1}{4}$. The book says it follows the logic of the stars and bars.
$$
\begin{align*}
\square\square&\square\square\\
xx\;\;\;&\;\;\;yy
\end{align*}
$$
$2$ and $12$ can be selected twice and $2$s are placed before $12$. However, I fail to understand this logic.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not clear on what your sentence '2 and 12 can be selected twice and 2s are placed before 12' means. However, putting that aside for the moment, the logic of the stars and bars approach would be as follows:

You are choosing four numbers from $\{2,4,9,12\}$ with repetition. Since order is unimportant, the only feature distinguishing one selection from another is how many of each of the four numbers is included.

Imagine permutations of four stars and three bars. The three bars would separate the stars into four groups, some of which might be empty. Each group of stars would indicate how many of a particular number is included in the selection; one possibility would be the first group of stars representing the number of $2$'s, the second group of stars representing the number of $4$'s, etc.

A couple of concrete examples of this would be

$$ \bigstar \bigstar \big| \big|\bigstar \big| \bigstar$$

which would represent the selection $(2,2,9,12)$, or

$$ \big| \bigstar \bigstar \bigstar \bigstar \big| \big|$$

which would represent $(4,4,4,4)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x_i$ be the number of times the $i$th smallest number appears in the selection.  Since four numbers are selected with repetition from the set $\{2, 4, 9, 12\}$,
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 4 \tag{1}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation $1$ corresponds to the placement of $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in a row of four ones.  For instance,
$$1 1 + 1 + 1 + $$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 2, x_2 = x_3 = 1, x_4 = 0$ and the selection with two $2$s, one $4$, one $9$, and no $12$s.  The number of such solutions is the number of ways we can place $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs in a row of $4$ ones, which is
$$\binom{4 + 4 - 1}{4 - 1} = \binom{7}{3}$$
since we must choose which three of the seven positions required for $4$ ones and $4 - 1 = 3$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.